# How do i use shared pref file for my app's log in page

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

In my application I got user info in shared pref file. When user enter their details on the log in page, I want only users whose info is in shared pref file to log in. How can I do that?

Comment: try to store username and password in your shared pref and while clicking on login button check if it correct or not.

Comment: use this link to know how to store and retrieve from `SharedPreferences` : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Didn't downvote, but check [ask] to know why, also hover the mouse in the DV arrow, it shows the reasons.

Comment: sorry,i am very knew to stackoverflow.

Comment: not yet.none of the code is not showing how to validate data with shared pref file

Comment: what exactly u want explain once i will help u by code

Comment: i got one signup page from where i am saving data to my shared pref file and that is working fine.i know that we can use getstring method to retrieve data from shared pref file but how should it validate username and password,whenever user enters data on loginpage.like if theur account info is not stored in shared pref file.it will give them error message account not found etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your apps shared preferences. The prefs can be accessed anytime using the key you set for these **prefs**.

```
static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
 static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

 if (saveLogInDetail) { //save username and pw to prefs
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor ed = prefs.edit();
      ed.putString(KEY_USERNAME, theUsername);
      ed.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, thePW);
      ed.commit();
 }
```

To access the information or check the valid **username** and **password** use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String storedUsername = prefs.getString(KEY_USERNAME, "Default Value if not found");
 String storedPassword = prefs.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, ""); //return nothing if no pass saved
```

Comment: gud example you have given simple to understand

Comment: i dont know what i am doing?not working for me:(

Comment: that's the part which i dont know.

Comment: the `username` and `password` which you are getting through the **login** screen compare it with the `storedUsername` and `storedPassword` of prefs.

Answer (score 1):

Store your login data in sharedpreferences:
 String username="dipali";
 String pass="1111";

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = viewLoginScreen
                                                .getSharedPreferences(
                                                        "prefernce",
                                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                        editor.putString(
                                                "username",
                                                user);
                                        editor.commit();


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = viewLoginScreen
                                            .getSharedPreferences(
                                                    "prefernce",
                                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                    editor.putString(
                                            "pass",
                                            pass);
                                    editor.commit();
```

get shared prefences data:

```
SharedPreferences shar = viewLoginScreen
                                        .getSharedPreferences(
                                                "prefernce",
                                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username=shar.getString("username","");
String pass=shar.getString("pass","");
```

Comment: diplai but where it will check with the data we are entering in the log in screen.according to that code we are fetching data from shared pref file but how to validate with the data user is entering in username and password fields.

Comment: please check my edited post.and if any query tell me.

Comment: @dipali i have query...

Comment: @dipali have you used Audio Track for generate Tone??

Comment: please give me some description of your query.

Comment: @dipali tone generate karva mate jema eni frequency and amplitude change thay 6

Comment: no i am not using audio track for generate tone.

Comment: @dipali okay no problem.....

Answer (score -1):

you should use SQlite Database instead of using share preference. Once you set up database then insert user credentials to database if user is a not register. And in your case check if current user is in database if exits authenticate him other wise you can force him to register to application. You can see sqlite in detail  here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: but it is my assignment and i need to shared prefrences only.

Comment: the benefit of using shared prrefrence every time he don't need to take user name and password.once your u r details u can acess the app .simple

Comment: I think you have to make share preference for each individuals who  login into your application which is very in efficient. so i suggest to use database. if you want to do with share preference you can use @Ryderz's answer

Comment: @GauravPandey i didn't think in that way. yeaps in that case share preference is awesome :) and of course question is not clear

Comment: a single device will not be used by all the user every user will have his own device so this is better why to consume our space on server