# Android: How to check for valid login from SQLite with Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, shared

I am trying to implement sessions (shared Preferences) with my sqlite database.

I have Username and Password fields that I'd like to save to shared preferences. However, I only want to do this if the login is valid.

If it is valid login, sign in the user (go to next activity as specified) and save it in the shared preferences. This is my goal; however, I am having trouble implementing this.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.votingapp;

import com.example.votingapp.library.DatabaseHandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputUserName;
    EditText inputUserPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;
    DatabaseHandler database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setting default screen to activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        inputUserPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserPass);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        //SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);

        String username = settings.getString("username", null);
        String password = settings.getString("password", null);

        if(!(username==null) && !(password==null)){
            Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(dashboard);
            finish();
        }

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName = inputUserName.getText().toString();
                String userPass = inputUserPass.getText().toString();
                boolean validLogin = validateLogin(userName, userPass, MainActivity.this);

                //SharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                if(validLogin){
                    editor.putString("username", userName);
                    editor.putString("password", userPass);
                    editor.commit();

                }else{
                    inputUserName.setText(settings.getString("username", ""));
                    inputUserPass.setText(settings.getString("password", ""));
                }



                if(userName.equals("") || userName == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(userPass.equals("") || userPass == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(validLogin){ 
                        //Show a dialog of login successful
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        //Close views before starting Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            }
            });//Login Button On SetListener

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(Register);
                finish();
            }
        });//Register Button onClickListener

    }//On Create


    public boolean validateLogin(String userName, String userPass, Context context) {

        DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        //SELECT
        String[] columns = {"userId"};

        //WHERE clause
        String selection = "userName=? AND userPass=?";

        //WHERE clause arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {userName, userPass};
        Cursor c = null;

        try{
        //SELECT userId FROM login WHERE username=userName AND password=userPass
        c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_USERS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        c.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int i = c.getCount();
        if(i <= 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }//validate Login

}//Mainactivity
```

Comment: Please note that shared preferences are stored in an xml file which users can get access to. You should encrypt your password or store its hash.

Comment: yes, I will be doing that. Im currently in the initial stage of this application. Any help on what I asked above?

Comment: But what is exactly the problem?

Comment: problem is I like to save the username and the password using shared preferences only if it is valid. As stated in the code, I'm checking for validation through SQLite Database

Answer (score 1):

you are not storing  username and password of text field to SharedPreferences but your code store null value to sharedPreferences. Try this code

```
package com.example.votingapp;

import com.example.votingapp.library.DatabaseHandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputUserName;
    EditText inputUserPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;
    DatabaseHandler database;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setting default screen to activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        inputUserPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserPass);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);




        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName = inputUserName.getText().toString();
                String userPass = inputUserPass.getText().toString();

                if(userName.equals("") || userName == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(userPass.equals("") || userPass == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    boolean validLogin = validateLogin(userName, userPass, MainActivity.this);
                    if(validLogin){ 

                        //SharedPreferences
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
                        inputUserName.setText(settings.getString("username", ""));
                        inputUserPass.setText(settings.getString("password", ""));

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("username", userName);
                        editor.putString("password", userPass);
                        editor.commit();

                        String username = settings.getString("username", null);
                        String password = settings.getString("password", null);

                        if(!(username==null) && !(password==null)){
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            finish();
                        }
                        //Show a dialog of login successful
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        //Close views before starting Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            }
            });//Login Button On SetListener

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(Register);
                finish();
            }
        });//Register Button onClickListener

    }//On Create


    public boolean validateLogin(String userName, String userPass, Context context) {

        DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        //SELECT
        String[] columns = {"userId"};

        //WHERE clause
        String selection = "userName=? AND userPass=?";

        //WHERE clause arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {userName, userPass};
        Cursor c = null;

        try{
        //SELECT userId FROM login WHERE username=userName AND password=userPass
        c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_USERS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        c.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int i = c.getCount();
        if(i <= 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }//validate Login

}//Mainactivity
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but no luck. Take a look at my edited code, it seems to do what I wanted, but Im not sure if it is efficient enough. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing `UserName` and `Password` in Database you can use `SharedPreferences` to store it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843625/how-do-i-use-shared-pref-file-for-my-apps-log-in-page/18843908#18843908)

Answer (score 0):

In ValidateLogin(), You are closing cursor and after closing it, you are calling cursor.getCount(). It is wrong. Check my edited code.

```
package com.example.votingapp;

import com.example.votingapp.library.DatabaseHandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputUserName;
    EditText inputUserPass;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;
    DatabaseHandler database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setting default screen to activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        inputUserPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserPass);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        //SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);

        String username = settings.getString("username", null);
        String password = settings.getString("password", null);

        if(username!=null && password!=null){
            Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(dashboard);
            finish();
        }

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName = inputUserName.getText().toString();
                String userPass = inputUserPass.getText().toString();
                boolean validLogin = validateLogin(userName, userPass, MainActivity.this);

                if(validLogin){

                    //SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", userName);
                    editor.putString("password", userPass);
                    editor.commit();

                }else{
                    inputUserName.setText(settings.getString("username", ""));
                    inputUserPass.setText(settings.getString("password", ""));
                }



                if(userName.equals("") || userName == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(userPass.equals("") || userPass == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(validLogin){ 
                        //Show a dialog of login successful
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        //Close views before starting Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            }
            });//Login Button On SetListener

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(Register);
                finish();
            }
        });//Register Button onClickListener

    }//On Create


    public boolean validateLogin(String userName, String userPass, Context context) {

        DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        //SELECT
        String[] columns = {"userId"};

        //WHERE clause
        String selection = "userName=? AND userPass=?";

        //WHERE clause arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {userName, userPass};
        Cursor c = null;

        try{
        //SELECT userId FROM login WHERE username=userName AND password=userPass
        c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_USERS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int i = c.getCount();
c.close();        
if(i <= 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
            }

        return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
return false;
        }
    }//validate Login

}//Mainactivity
```