# android pass the username and password in edittext of another activity

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing android application with login. When the user logged in i want to pass both username and password to another activity in another edittext. The passed username and password should be displayed in the another edittext of another activity. the password should look as it is (not revealing characters). I know that it may sound like weird but is that possible? Just give me an answer i know you might ask why should i display this thing to another edittext but i have my own purpose.

This is what i need to pass to another edittext

```
inputusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPasswod);

imgLogin1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = inputusername.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(username, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_PSUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_PSUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_PUSERNAME), json.getString(KEY_PUID), json_user.getString(KEY_PCREATED_AT));                     

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PatientHomeActivity.class);
                            dashboard.putExtra(KEY_PUSERNAME,username);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
```

**EDIT**
Here's where i have passed the data

```
 private static final String TAG_PUSERNAME = "username";
 private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        /*
         * Start and bind the  imService 
         **/
        startService(new Intent(Login.this,  IMService.class));         


        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
        setTitle("Login");
        Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();

        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_login);
        usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        usernameText.setText(i.getString(TAG_PUSERNAME));
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password); 
        passwordText.setText(i.getString(TAG_PASSWORD));
```

That's the next activity where the data should be passed.

Comment: You are already passing the username in an extra, why not just pass the password also?

Comment: just have edittext with `android:inputType="textPassword"` and use intent to pass values

Comment: Saved it to `sharedPreferences` like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843625/how-do-i-use-shared-pref-file-for-my-apps-log-in-page/18843908#18843908 and you can use it throughout your application.. set `edittext` to `android:inputType="textPassword"`.

Comment: guys i have a problem. i can't pass that data to EditText. please check my edit! @Raghunandan can u help me?

Comment: Can u guys help me. still having a problem. need to pass the data from EDittext to another EditText.. @GregEnnis

Comment: yeah yeah..its working now. tnx guys for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Bundle to pass the value from current activity to next acivity

**Current Activtiy to pass data**

```
Intent i = new Intent (BundleActivity.this,datapass.class);
Bundle b =new Bundle();
b.putString("Username","your Username editext value");
b.putString("Password","your Password editext value");
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

**In Next activity to receive data**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String Username= b.getString("Username");
String Password= b.getString("Password");
```

Answer (score 3):

For passing data from onr activity to other you can use intents or shared preference.

**For setting password as non revealing character in edit textbox**  :Set this `android:inputType="phone"` to editbox of your second activity in which you are showing password in Xml Layout **OR** from your activity you can also dynamically set this as `userPassword.setInputType(129)`(it will make text into password ).Hope it will help.