# How to disable the EDIT-TEXT in android for entire activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How to disable the edit-text after clicking a button for entire activity?
Here I have two or more activities

Example: 
Activity A and B contains both Edit_text and Button
In Activity A entered some values in edit_text and click the ok button now In coding part I mentioned that `EditText1.setEnabled(false)`.
Here the `EditText1` is disabled now 
After switching to Activity B, and From Activity B to Activity A. Now the `EditText1` is enabled

Can any one tell me how to disable the `EditText1` for entire activity 
Thanks In Advance

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             final String sq=ed.getText().toString();
            if(sq.equals("a") || sq.equals("A"))
            {
             RESULT++;
            display.setText(""+RESULT);}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Activity A` read the `EditText1` i.e `findviewbyid` and  set `EditText1.setEnabled(false)` on `onResume()` method of Activity Lifecycle.

On `Button` clicked use this :

```
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityA.this);
              Editor ed = prefs.edit();
              ed.putBoolean(BUTTON_CLICKED, true);
              ed.commit();
              EditText1.setEnabled(false); 
              final String sq=ed.getText().toString();
                if(sq.equals("a") || sq.equals("A"))
                {
                 RESULT++;
                display.setText(""+RESULT);}
            }

        });
```

on `onResume` :

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     Boolena buttonClicked = prefs.getBoolean(BUTTON_CLICKED, false);
      if(buttonClicked){
     EditText EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    EditText1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to disable after triggering the button

Comment: Use `SharedPreference` to store the `Button` clicked state ... then all you have to do is just check the button state through `SharedPreference` and accordingly enable or disable the `EditText`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843625/how-do-i-use-shared-pref-file-for-my-apps-log-in-page/18843908#18843908 .

Comment: any example for that?

Comment: Posted the code now say where i want to add your part?

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  In this Line IT Showing that rename your file ?????

Comment: Are you using any other SharedPreferences in your Activity.

Comment: Can U Please give any other example regarding this

Answer (score 0):

write your code inside onResume() section of activity