# Having trouble skipping an activity

Tags: java, android

My Android app has a login screen and the user logs in to his dashboard. But I don't want the user to login every time they close the app and start it (unless they logout from the dashboard). So, I created a class to check if the user logged in

**CheckLoggedIn.java**

```
public class CheckLoggedIn extends Activity {

    private boolean isLoggedIn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!isLoggedIn){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AgentHome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    public boolean getStatus(){
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status){
        isLoggedIn = status;
    }

}
```

When user logs in, I change the boolean `isLoggedIn` to `true` and `false` when logs out. But when I checked it by logging in successfully and closing it and starting it again, it still goes to LoginActivity. Why?

Edit : Now, I've understood it's because I set the boolean `isLoggedIn` to `false` at the beginning of the CheckLoggedIn.java. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

EDIT 2 :

**Preference.java**

```
public class Preference {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    public Preference(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginState", 0);
    }

    public boolean getIsLoggedIn(){
        return sharedPref.getBoolean("State", false);
    }

    public void setIsLoggedIn(boolean state){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("State", state);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Preference preference = new Preference(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(preference.getIsLoggedIn()){
        Log.d("State", "Already logged in");
    }
            ......
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450): Process: collector.lbfinance, PID: 21450
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{collector.lbfinance/collector.lbfinance.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at collector.lbfinance.library.Preference.<init>(Preference.java:13)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at collector.lbfinance.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:52)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-17 16:30:53.063: E/AndroidRuntime(21450):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` to store the value of `isLoggedIn` (or any other data storage options that better suits your needs). More infos here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Why are you creating an unnecessary class which is useless. Simply use shared preference save the value of your login to true in a boolean variable and so on

Comment: Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843625/how-do-i-use-shared-pref-file-for-my-apps-log-in-page/18843908#18843908 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [shared preferences](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html&ei=jOMBU7feKceJrQeXbA&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&sig2=yrJ2GvdtrrSH4Lel60fqNw&bvm=bv.61535280,d.bmk) for this purpose. Your Boolean variable is only valid till your activity is not destroyed.To persist data you will have to use shared preferences or [sqlite](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEUQFjAB&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html&ei=OeQBU9z4LsTArAeCqIH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGHrlZI8DewY8QwqR2vRa37N2GJpg&sig2=z3vLWg13ITiAFPqIT1R2gw&bvm=bv.61535280,d.bmk).

Using sqlite is only advised when we have Relational database ,for lightweight persistent storage of app seetings etc shared preferences is best .

> ```
> public class PreferenceForApp {
>   Context context;
>   SharedPreferences prefs;
>
>   public PreferenceForApp(Context context) {
>       this.context = context;
>       prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);
>   }
>
>   public Boolean getIsDeviceValidated() {
>
>       return prefs.getBoolean("Validated", false);
>   }
>
>   public void setIsDeviceValidated(Boolean value) {
>
>       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
>       editor.putBoolean("Validated", value);
>       editor.commit();
>   }
> }
> ```

**EDIT**

In your Activity call this function and pass context to it in the following way :

```
PreferenceForApp myPrefs= new PreferenceForApp (this);

Boolean val=myPrefs.getIsDeviceValidated();
```

Comment: Tried this method. But it gives a NullPointerException at the line prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);

Comment: I'm still getting the NullPointerException.
In my MainActivity, I did the above (calling the function I mean). But the App doesn't even start. It crashes immediately. When debugged, the debug window shows Source Not Found in ContextWrapper

Comment: Added to the main question

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed Move `Preference preference = new Preference(this);` to `onCreate()` - you cannot use the activity as a Context before `onCreate()`.

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed Correctly pointed out by laalto .Just move the said line in on create.

Comment: Oh, and side question. Can I use SharedPreferences inside onOptionsItemSelected function?

Comment: yes you can or simply use getApplicationContext() instead of this .Both will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the values of credentials.

To store values in SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("userName", "value");
editor.putString("password", "value");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve values from SharedPreference,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("loginData", 0);
String userName = preferences.getString("userName", "");
String password = preferences.getString("password", "");
```