# If apps got login already goto main activty else go to login page in android

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

Hai guys greetings to all ...
 Am New To Android Field..I created New Android apps Using  Login and registeration screen... My Question Is I want If my apps got login by user already goto menu activty else go to login page in android.. Please Help Me By Giving Sample coding or idea..Thanks In Advance..

This Is The Code am using. for My Qs , But its not Working..

```
 package com.example.android_todist;
 import java.util.logging.Handler;
  import java.util.regex.Matcher;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Dialog;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
  import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
   import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
Intent intent;
String userName,password;
  SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
     pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String storedUsername = pref.getString(userName, "");
 String storedPassword = pref.getString(password, ""); //return nothing if no pass       saved
if (!storedUsername .equalsIgnoreCase("") || !storedPassword .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, Todist1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}else {
    Intent  intent  = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
        public void run() {

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);

}
```

}

it will redirect to main page . but If the new user open My apps it will also redirect to main page cant able to get login page..

This Is My Error log..:

```
   07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): java.lang.NullPointerException
   07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):  at   
   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1410)

  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at 
  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at   
  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at 
  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at
  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at   
        com.example.android_todist.SplashActivity$1.run(SplashActivity.java:50)

  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at 
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at 
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at  
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at  
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):   at  
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):    at

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-24 04:21:36.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843625/how-do-i-use-shared-pref-file-for-my-apps-log-in-page/18843908#18843908

Comment: Please Look Into My coding...

Comment: Remove `import java.util.logging.Handler;`

Comment: Your coding is working is working .. But if the intnet is reached Login activty..The project is stopped.. Shows Error android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity   example.android_todist.SplashActivity$1.run   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

Comment: sorry I already Tried that .. have 15 + Reputation for upload image ..

Comment: Now I upload My Apps error logcat.. Please Help to Solve my issue..

Comment: We Have toa dd anything in R.layout.splash_screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SplashActivity` class and here you check for the credentials .

```
    public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        Intent intent;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String storedUsername = prefs.getString(KEY_USERNAME, "Default Value if not found");
 String storedPassword = prefs.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, ""); //return nothing if no pass saved
if (!storedUsername .equalsIgnoreCase("") || !storedPassword .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            intent  = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }else {
            intent  = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           }

            Handler handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 3000);

        }

    }// class
```

Comment: Thanks For Your reply , Actually ..Already Stored Login user Details using Shared preferences..My need is If The user Open My apps..if They Already login Means ..Redirect main page Else redirect to Login Page...

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { On Handler Cannot instantiate the type Handler on postDelayed Add cast to hnadler..}

Comment: What error are you getting ?? post the Logcat value .

Comment: SOrry I got Red Underlined error ..showed { On Handler Cannot instantiate the type Handler on postDelayed Add cast to hnadler..}

Comment: `import android.os.Handler;`   import ths to your code .

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to maintain a splash screen activity to your application.
2. By using shared preferences you have to save your login state (default "false", after login "true") refer this link for preferences  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
3. At time of launching application you have to check the login state, based on that value you can navigate to respective Activity.

Comment: if you already logged into the device it is going to Main activity correctly, but if you want go login activity for other users in the same device you should log out first, that you have to save false in preferences.

Comment: I Already Stored Login user Details using Shared preferences..My need is If The user Open My apps..if They Already login Means ..Redirect main page Else redirect to Login Page..